# How to control appearance of extra cursors?

Tags: multiple-cursors

I've just switched to “I-beam” cursor shape, it's set this way:

```el
(setq-default
 cursor-type '(bar . 1)
 cursor-in-non-selected-windows nil)
```

But when I create additional cursors they are displayed as filled boxes
(while “main” cursor is displayed according to my settings). This doesn't
look good.

Is there any way to control appearance of additional cursors? Ideally, they
should mimic appearance of “main” cursor.

Comment: I started to look into the source, it seems like additional cursors are implemented as overlays which use special faces. It may be extremely difficult to mimic I-beam cursor using overlays...

Comment: If the original poster is creating additional cursors with the `multiple-cursors` library -- https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el -- then changing the appearance of *fake cursors* to mimic an **I-beam** cursor can be accomplished with an overlay by concatenating a zero-width character with the target character, or by creating an XPM of every character normally used and incorporating a vertical bar (testing for the foreground/background at point, and colorizing each xpm accordingly):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744237/emacs-how-to-create-a-vertical-strike-through-effect

Comment: Here is a link to the feature request that I submitted to the Emacs team on June 3, 2014 (#17684) -- there was never any interest/response:  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17684